# Selecting Rails environment with "rails generate" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I can start server/console, run a rake task in `local` environment using the following commands:

```
rails s -e local    

rails c local

rake RAILS_ENV=local db:migrate
```

How can I run `rails generate (or rails g)` in `local` environment?

Comment: What would `rails generate` do differently in some environment?

Comment: I'm getting database connect error if my current environment is different from `development`

Comment: What current environment? Sorry to be so blunt but I have never seen any environment options with generate commands. They just generate code and that doesn't depend on environment settings. Are your config/database.yml settings correct?

Comment: I have many environments with different db settings for each of them in config/database.yml. Due to some issues I can't use development environment and use my own called local. When I run rails g it uses db settings for development environment by default and generates an error because db settings for it are for a different server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
RAILS_ENV=local rails g ...
```

Ought to work. That's setting the env var with the shell rather than relying on rails reading a command line option.

Comment: Is there a difference between specifying it at the start and at the end of a task/command?