# Can environment variables be provided for RubyMine tasks?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

Can environment variables be provided for RubyMine tasks (such as "rails generate") as project-level configuration?

To be clear -- I'm **not** referring to run/debug configurations, except if a mechanism is available to use environment variables defined in such a configuration during calls to Ruby performed from other parts of RubyMine (or the IntelliJ Ruby plugin -- which is built from the same codebase as RubyMine, and is what I'm actually using).

---

RubyMine makes it straightforward to configure environment variables in effect when a program is being run or debugged. Consider, by contrast, the situation given here: [Selecting Rails environment with "rails generate" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685224/selecting-rails-environment-with-rails-generate-command)

...wherein a user has an issue resolved by ensuring that an environment variable is set whenever RubyMine invokes `rails generate` within their project.

How can this solution be extended to RubyMine?